# Prepopulated Android Room database stays empty

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-room-prepackageddatabase

I'm using Room version 2.2.6., Android Studio 4.2.2 and writing in Java.

I filled my app's database manually interacting with the app in an emulator, and it shows up both in the app and in the database inspector as one would expect. I built a certain initial example state that I would like my users to have upon first start. I then downloaded the `.db .db-shm .db-wal` files straight from the device file explorer and saved them in src/main/assets/databases/ as one does.

In my database initialization code I added the line `.createFromAsset("databases/Example.db")` between the `.databaseBuilder` and `.build` calls, to prepopulate my database from those files.

Yet after wiping my local data and reinstalling the app, the database stays empty.

Any clue what direction I could search in? All the posts here I found relating to createFromAsset only contain the same copied paragraph from the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createFromAsset()` assumes that just the `.db` file is needed.

So, close the database first before copying. If you have `.db-shm` and `.db-wal` files, you did not close the database first.

Comment: That would have been a really useful detail to mention in the documentation. But then, they didn't even really give much information for how to obtain such a .db file in the first place, so I guess they just assumed anyone who'd want to prepopulate databases would know already. Do I need to close that from code? Where would I sensibly do so?

Comment: @lenkva: FWIW, [this sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-room/-/tree/v0.5/PackagedFTS) demonstrates `createFromAsset()`.

Comment: @lenkva: "Do I need to close that from code?" -- yes, assuming that is your code that is where you are populating your starter database. "Where would I sensibly do so?" -- perhaps when the user clicks the "Backup" or "Export" option in your app. [This sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-room/-/tree/v0.5/ImportExport) (covered in [the same book as the first sample](https://commonsware.com/Room)) demonstrates this process.

Comment: I don't have a "Backup" Button. My intention wasn't to backup data, just to have an initial state so my users aren't greeted with an entirely bare app, in order to guide them a little in what they can do. Lacking general expertise with databases, I figured I'd create that state, then manually export it and use it for prepopulation. I put the .close-instruction in my Main Activity's onDestroy. That did the job, and I now have one file only. I still get an error, but it's a different one, so for all purposes, this one is solved - thanks!